# Auto-assign workflow in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to assign individual list items to a que of individuals on a rotating basis.

Here's essentially what I am trying to do:

Names:
Bob S
Joe B
Emily R

In a SharePoint list, if some user (outside of these three people or including these three people) adds an item to the list, an alert would be sent to bob, and bob only, also a cell in that list item row would hopefully populate with Bob's name as assigned to that item. The same thing would happen if a new list item is added, but it would be assigned to Joe, and then Emily, and then back to bob, and so on.

Is there any way to do this: workflow settings or some other way?

Comment: A few questions to determine what options are available: What version of SharePoint are you using? Do you have access to SharePoint Designer? Do you have access to log on to the SharePoint servers and perform administrative tasks?

Comment: SharePoint 2013. I do not have access to designer, however If that's the only way to accomplish this, I could probably find someone that does have access. I have access to site administration for our particular site, but not server administration

Comment: `ID mod 3` or dynamic number based on items count?

Answer (score 0):

Using ID mod 3 would help you round robin the items between the number of targets, but to solve the problem of having just that person notified that the item was assigned to them would require a second list.  It would need to be a Task list to be specific.  You can then create a Power Automate workflow on the first list that will create a Task in the second list and assign it to a specific person.  Have the three users setup alerts on the second list to be notified when a Task it assigned to them.  This will provide you with a crude but quick solution.

Note, I do not recommend doing the email notification in Power Automate because that would mean you'd have to create a second flow on the Task list in order to notify someone if the given task was re-assigned.  Instead, SharePoint's built in Alerts notification system should do the trick just fine.